# trying to get the date/average from selenuim

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Using Python 3.8 I need to get the date/year and the average from a website and save it under an Excel sheet.
The structure is as follows

1. 01/01/2014 – 01/01/2015 2.1
2. 01/01/2016 – 01/01/2017 1.0
3. 01/01/2018 – 01/01/2019 4.0

I want to save all the dates/month/year under each cell including the  average
Example

- ```
   Cell 1              Cell 2
  ```
- Row1 01/01/2014 – 01/01/2015 2.1
- Row1 01/01/2016 – 01/01/2017 1.0

So I pull the web elements as follows

```
Dates_avg = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='performance']")
```

This would contain all the information (dates/month/year and the average).
I am trying to find a way to segregate them.
I tried datetime, trying to convert as above, so I can apply something like below

```
Dates_avg = str(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='performance']"))
data1_1 = dt.datetime.strptime(Dates_avg '"%d-%m-%Y"').date()
```

Without success. Any help would be greatly apricated
thanks in advance

Apologies for the delay in response. Kindly see the HTML tag for this.
Also, I understand once I import this "Dates_avg" it's a list. I am trying to figure out how to get this list and convert to date/month/year and put them on an Excel, so I can run some reports/stats
Also note, this page is dynamically loaded, s there is no static link

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
       <th scope="row">
                       <span class="performance">30/08/15</span> - <span class="performanceEnd">30/08/16</span>
       </th>
       <td class="value">11.22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
                        <span class="performance">30/08/16</span> - <span class="performanceEnd">30/08/17</span>
        </th>
        <td class="value">10.12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
                        <span class="performance">30/08/17</span> - <span class="performanceEnd">30/08/18</span>
        </th>
        <td class="value"> 5.16</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
                        <span class="performance">30/08/18</span> - <span class="performanceEnd">30/08/19</span>
         </th>
         <td class="value">-0.64</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
                        <span class="performance">30/08/19</span> - <span class="performanceEnd">30/08/20</span>
    </th>
        <td class="value">-1.55</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: `Dates_avg = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='performance']")` will returns list of elements not the values.Please [edit] your post with relevant HTML.

Comment: Pls provide the webpage's url.